How can I draw a smooth line using Z Math Surface function?
I'm trying to create a curve line (like a laser pulse) using Add > Mesh > Math Function > Z Math Surface with equation $3 \sin(20y) e^{-5y^2}$ (3*sin(20*y)*e**(-5*y*y)):


However, the line doesn't look super smooth because Y subdivisions can go up to 256. Is there a more proper way to get the job done with a custom equation like this?
I am still pretty new to Blender so I don't have extensive knowledge or experience.

I think it is not related to how many subdivisions you have, but to some parameters you can increase in the Object Data Properties panel. In Active Spline tab, you could try to increase Resolution U. You could also increase the Resolution Preview U in Shape tab.

It seems like the minimum is 3 subdivisions on the X. Just do that

Then select these edge loops and press X > Vertices to delete these edge loops.

Convert to Curve and then edit the curve properties to get this pretty profile:

To make the highest tip a bit smoother you can add a subdivision modifier to get curve to get something like this:

